# Searching for a Name in a Global using a Partial Name

Tags: intersystems-cache, mumps

I created a name global and I am trying to print out a matching name by using only using the same characters that the name starts with. Example: Enter Sm and return the value Smith, John A.

I created this:

```
N prompt,val
S prompt="Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI): "
F  W !,prompt R val Q:val=""  D
.   I val'?1.A1",".1" "1.A.1(1" "1A) W !,"Invalid name"
.   E  S ^ZNAME(val)=""
F  S val=$O(^ZNAME(val)) Q:val=""  D
.   W !,"You entered: ",val
Q
```

I entered two names and got the desired result.^ZNAME("MITCHELL, DAVID J")^ZNAME ("SMITH, JOHN A").

I want to to be able to read a partial name and it search the ^ZNAME and return the value it matches. In this case read "Sm" and return "Smith, John A."

```
N partial,val
S partial="Enter a name or partial name: "
F  W !,partial R val Q:val=""  D
.   W !,$O(^ZNAME("val"))
Q
```

When I enter "Sm" from the read command it loops back to Enter a name or partial name instead of giving me the desired result of Smith, John A. I am missing something I know it, but a little burnt out. Any help will be great thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got double quotes around val:

```
.   W !,$O(^ZNAME("val"))
Q
```

So it is trying to write the value at ^ZNAME("val") which there isn't one. Remove the double quotes and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I took out the double quotes as instructed. It is still looping back to the read command.

Comment: I went back and entered in SM instead of Sm with the removal of the double quotes as instructed and it worked! Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Yeah. Mumps is a case sensitive language so Smith will be different that SMITH. I didn't catch that you had the uppercase version stored in the global. GLad you got it working!

Comment: I have an additional question. How would I adjust this code to loop over only the names that match the search string rather than every name in the array?